# Supress the Soft Keboard when an activity loads... yet again

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Same problem that I've read on other posts. I don't want the soft keyboard to pop up when the Activity loads. The above code snippet works, however my View no longer scrolls up so that the User can still see the EditText.

It scrolls without this line of code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set right attribute on your activity in manifest
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: I have this...
<activity android:name="Activity" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"></activity>

Comment: You got me to thinking.. before trying the above code snippet.. I did this...

android:isScrollContainer="true"

When I remove that from the layout, it pans.

I find that odd.